# Decide if the following improper integral converges. If so, calculate value

Tags: definite-integrals

Show that $$\int_1^2\cfrac {dx}{x\ln^2 x}  \qquad \qquad \qquad (a)$$
Converges or diverges ,

I can think of using a substitution, $u=\ln x$ , $du=\cfrac 1xdx$

\begin{align}
& = \int_1^2\cfrac {dx}{x\ln^2 x}\\
& = \int_1^2\cfrac {du}{u^2}\\
& =  \lim \limits_{c \to 1^+}\int_c^2\cfrac {du}{u^2}                       \\
& =  \lim \limits_{c \to 1^+}[-1u^{-1}]|_c^2                            \\
& =  -\lim \limits_{c \to 1^+}[\frac 12-\frac1c ]      \\
& = \frac 12 \\
\end{align}
I am right? or what i've done wrong?

Comment: When you do the substitution you must change the limits of integration!

Comment: I noticed that, then is $\ln 2$ and $\ln 1 = 0$, thanks

Comment: Nothing!!!!!!!!! :) :) :)

Comment: For $x\to 1$, $\log(x)\sim x-1$.  Inasmuch as the integral $\int_0^1\frac1{x^2}\,dx$ diverges, the integral of interest does likewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are asked to evaluate $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x(\ln (x))^2}dx$.

As you suggested, change of variables is a good approach to this problem. Going by your suggestion, let $u(x) = \ln x$. It follows, $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$. However, we need to make changes to the limits of integrations too! That is the key. So $u(1) = \ln(1)=0$ and $u(2)=\ln(2)$. Therefore,

$$  \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x(\ln (x))^2}dx = \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{c}^{\ln(2)} \frac{1}{xu^2}xdu = \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{c}^{\ln(2)} \frac{1}{u^2}du $$

$$ = \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^+} \int_c^{\ln(2)} u^{-2} du = \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^+} (-\frac{1}{3u}) \big|_c^{\ln(2)} = (-\frac{1}{3\ln(2)})+ \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{3c}$$

The first term is a finite number and the second term goes to $+\infty$.

Hence, the integral diverges to $ \infty $.

Comment: Isn't it $\int\cfrac {1}{u^2}$ = $\cfrac{-1}{u}$ ?

Comment: My bad! Fixed it.